# .NET Core 6.0 FileContentResult wrong encoding

Tags: c#, .net-core, encoding, actionresult

I'm trying to view a generated PDF.

```
public ActionResult Print()
{
   byte[] result = this.PrintDocument();

   Response.Headers.Append("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
   return File(result, "application/pdf");
}
```

The file result corrupted and cannot be opened.

What I obtain is:

```
%PDF-1.4
%����
4 0 obj
<</Length 680/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
x��UKO1��^*J��%Yjţ*���VVmԐ7�FS�*���w�u6i e���(����7�o��>
2��2�y��
...
```

But if I save the `result` byte array directly in a file this can be proper opened and what I obtain is:

```
%PDF-1.4
%âãÏÓ
4 0 obj
<</Length 680/Filter/FlateDecode>>stream
xœÅUKO1‰Û^*Jô%YjÅ£*¿½¾VVmÔ7áFS©*¸ôïwìu6i eƒ„ª(»ÞñÌ7ão¾É>
...
```

Thinking about the charset I tried to change the `return File(result, "application/pdf");` line adding, for example, `"application/pdf; charset=utf-8"` and so on but without any result.

There is a way to avoiding the encoding inside FileContentResult or maybe return directly the result on the Response as usually did in pre-CORE version?

Comment: "The file result corrupted and cannot be opened." - How are you *consuming* the result? This is binary data - nothing should be doing *anything* with a character encoding...

Comment: You don't need the line `Response.Headers.Append("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");`, since you can just pass the fileName as a third parameter to `File`: `return File(result, "application/pdf", fileName);`. Either way, that doesn't make a difference and I can't reproduce the problem: my browser downloads the PDF file correctly and I can open it normally. As Jon suggested, I think this is much more about how you're handling the result on the client side.

Comment: Sorry.. was Response.Headers.Append("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + fileName + "\""); since I wanted to view the PDF directly inside a new page.. "attachment" was just to see the generated content source

Comment: Ah, I see that now with your edit. Well, I'm not able to reproduce your issue with ASP.NET 6.0. There seems to be something more to this than is present in the question. Do you perhaps have something on the client side that's treating the result as text rather than binary? Or is there some middleware that does something?